# timer in java button

Tags: java, swing, timer

I don't know how to put this code insid emy programs . Likee..if I click on the button or by mouse in JPanel (that's inside the original panel), the program will run

```
static  class Action implements ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Timer timer;
        long startTime = -1;
        long duration = 1200000  ;
        JLabel label = new JLabel;
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime < 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long clockTime = now - startTime;
                if (clockTime >= duration) {
                    clockTime = duration;
                    timer.stop();
                }
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");
                label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));
            }
        });
```

Comment: `new JLabel;`...?

Comment: what do you want to achiev with this code? If you want a button, that can be locked for a time, create a class for this

Comment: I wanna add this code inside the Jpanel , but I don't know how to do . even if I added it and created a class , JPanel didn't show me the timer @JarlikStepsto

Comment: What does "show me the timer" mean? Please take some time to improve your question by adding a clear statement on what exactly you want/ need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem of new programmers finding code then copying it and pasting it wherever they think is might work. As you've already realized....it's not that simple otherwise you obviously wouldn't be here seeking assistance.

There are a number of things going wrong with your provided code and this is exactly why I'll provide you with code to show you how this can work using a Local Timer within a JButton Action Event and point out some of the specific problems so that you can realize them for later on should you encounter this sort of thing again.

You don't need to declare your **timer** variable and then initialize it later on down the road. You can declare and initialize the **timer** variable right on the same line, for example:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
});
```

Your Long data type **startTime** variable will never work within a Local Timer or any Inner (local) Class for that matter where value changes will need to be made. For your **startTime** variable to be used within the Local Timer Class it needs to carry full scope there and to do that the variable needs to be declared as **final**. Uhhh, there is a problem with this though, you can not change the value within a final variable which is a requirement for this countdown timer to function properly. If we don't declare the **startTime** variable as **final** then we'll just end up with a ***"local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"*** compile error. The solution to this then is to declare and initialize the **startTime** variable within the Local Timer class itself like this:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
    long startTime = -1;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        ..................
        ..................
    }
});
```

That solves that little problem. Now you have yet another problem, you can't just up and stop your Timer from within itself using the Timer.stop() method as you've done (ie:  timer.stop(); ) within the Timer's **actionPerformed** event for the simple reason the variable timer has no proper scope there and can't see that it's been initialized. Yes, it'll probably compile and it'll most likely run right up until the timer.stop() method is called and then you'll end up getting a Runtime Exception (***"variable timer might not have been initialized"***). Not good, and don't think about catching the exception and letting bygones be bygones because your ultimately not stopping the Timer (crappy practice). You just need to get a little fancier with your stop and this will do the trick:

```
((Timer)event.getSource()).stop();
//event is the ActionEvent variable (usually evt in some IDE's).
```

Now, your **duration** variable, there is nothing wrong with this if you like to supply long number values for even 1 minute of timing. Works great if that's your thing but for me personally, I like simply entering 60 instead of 60000. It really doesn't matter if the value will be hard coded into place but if it will actually be a supplied value (regardless from where) then it's just better to supply seconds (IMHO) which would of course entail the use of an additional variable, for example:

```
int seconds = 10;
final long duration = seconds * 1000;
```

Now you only need to supply the number of seconds you want your Countdown Timer to be set at.

Another problem you have is that you've declared a variable named **label** to represent a JLabel but nowhere do you either reference that variable to an actual JLabel somewhere or add it to a frame or panel component. I thinking that you've already installed a JLabel within your GUI (if you have a GUI) in which case you will need to supply that JLabel variable name when you declare the **label** variable, like this:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)jLabel1;
```

This way the label variable represents the JLabel named **jLabel1** within your GUI.

And finally (and this is a biggy) your Timer simply wont run if you don't tell it to do so. Where do you do this, well, right under your Local Timer Class of course **:)** like this:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
    long startTime = -1;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        ..................
        ..................
    }
});
timer.start();
```

Anyways, here's is the full code as promised:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int seconds = 10;  // supply timer duration in seconds
    final long duration = seconds * 1000;   // calculate to milliseconds
    JLabel label = (JLabel)jLabel1;  //whichever JLabel is in GUI
    final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        long startTime = -1;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (startTime < 0) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long clockTime = now - startTime;
            if (clockTime >= duration) {
                clockTime = duration;
                ((Timer)event.getSource()).stop(); // stop the Timer
                label.setText("Time Is UP"); // remove if you want or maybe just ""
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");
            label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```